# How do you enforce type checking of declared input types of a function without using check-type?

Tags: types, common-lisp, declare

Let's take an example :

```
(defun hello (a b)
  (declare (ftype (function (integer list) t) hello))
  (format t "Hello World"))
```

I would like to have a SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR raised when I call it like this :

```
> (hello 'a 12)
Hello World
```

But it gives me no error.

I've read that one should use CHECK-TYPE to check types at runtime, like this :

```
(defun hello (a b)
  (declare (ftype (function (integer list) t) hello))
  (check-type a integer)
  (check-type b list)
  (format t "Hello World"))

> (hello 'a 12)
The value of A is A, which is not of type INTEGER.
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]
```

But what's the point to (declare (ftype...) if it's not enforced at runtime and that I must add all those CHECK-TYPE forms ?

What's the best and idiomatic way of type checking parameters passed to a function and also type checking the returned value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer.

**Firstly** the `ftype` declaration you have does not do what you think, unfortunately.  From [3.3.4](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_cd.htm):

> A free declaration in a form F1 that applies to a binding for a name N established by some form F2 of which F1 is a subform affects only references to N within F1; it does not to apply to other references to N outside of F1, nor does it affect the manner in which the binding of N by F2 is established.

In other words in a form like

```
(defun foo (...)
  (declare (ftype foo ...))
  ...
```

The declaration applies only to references to `foo` *within the body of `foo`*: it does not apply elsewhere.  So it tells (or may tell) the compiler things about possible recursive calls to `foo`, only.

So if you want to make a global proclamation about a function you need to say

```
(declaim (ftype foo ...))
...
(defun foo (...)
  ...)
```

**Secondly** how declarations are interpreted is notoriously compiler-specific, in particular whether they are interpreted as assertions about the program which must be checked, or as declarations that something is the case which the compiler may assume.  CMUCL and implementations derived from it (notably SBCL today) take the former interpretation (at least with high safety settings, I think), all other implementations I know of take the latter.

As an example of this if I write

```
(declaim (ftype (function (integer integer)
                          (values integer integer))
                foo))

(defun foo (a b)
  (values a b))
```

Then SBCL will say:

```
> (describe 'foo)
common-lisp-user::foo
  [symbol]

foo names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (a b)
  Declared type: (function (integer integer)
                  (values integer integer &rest t))
  Derived type: (function (integer integer)
                 (values integer integer &optional))
```

and `(foo 'a 'b)` will signal an error.

However there's just no promise that that will happen in portable code at all.

Probably a better approach for portable code is

- declare the types of *arguments* to functions;
- write a `defun/checked` macro which turns those declarations into explicit checks in some cases.

There is still a slight problem in that systems which take the traditional 'declarations are things the compiler can trust' approach may take code which, after macroexpansion, ends up looking like

```
(defun foo (a)
  (declare (type fixnum a))
  (check-type a fixnum)
  ...)
```

and simply eliding the type check, since they are trusting what you told the compiler.  So you may need to have some settings for `defun/checked` where it simply elides the type declarations altogether so that the checks do what they are intended to.

I don't think this is the right place to put such a `defun/checked` macro but it's fairly easy to write one.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun hello (a b)
  (declare (ftype (function (integer list) t) hello))
  (check-type a integer)
  (check-type b list)
  (format t "Hello World"))
```

Here the scope of the `declare` for `hello` is wrong, this only applies to calls to `hello` inside your function. You typically need to have a global declaration, using `declaim`:

```
(declaim (ftype (function integer list) t) hello)
```

Then:

```
(defun hello (...) ...)
```

Or, you can add the type declaration for each argument, either by grouping all declarations in a single `declare` or adding multiple `declare` forms:

```
(defun hello (a b)
  (declare (type integer a))
  (declare (type list b))
  (format t "Hello World"))
```

Now, whether this type declaration is useful or not depends on your implementation: often `declare` for `type` is a way to give the compiler information it doesn't know, and the compiler has to trust the programmer here.

In some environments, and I am mostly familiar with SBCL here, the declaration is interpreted as an assertion: if the compiler can infer that the declaration holds, then it won't add a type check; otherwise, it will add a dynamic type check and the rest of code can assume the declaration holds (this also depends on the safety level, typically `0` means trusting the programmer at runtime,  while the default safety levels add checks).

That being said, type safety in Common Lisp is to be treated in a different ways than in statically-typed languages: functions can be redefined while your program runs, and even thought the SBCL compiler will warn you if the type signature changes in an incompatible way, concretely functions cannot trust their callers. Maybe there is someone writing:

```
(eval (read-from-string "(package::function invalid-argument)"))
```

Or maybe the argument to `eval` is the result of a Lisp function being called, etc. So there is no way to prove that all the calls are well-formed. That's why functions must maintain a safety bubble around them, by checking their arguments and producing valid Lisp values.

Inside a functions, and that's partly why some functions end-up being large, the world is a lot more static: you can declare a variable as being a `(unsigned-byte 64)` and a whole machine word will be used, without tagging, as long as it does not escape the scope of the function (if that's the case, it will be converted back to a Lisp `integer`).

I want to point out also that there is a library named [Coalton](https://github.com/coalton-lang/coalton) that implements a ML-like language with a more static-typing approach.

Answer (score 2):

The actual use of type declarations by a Common Lisp implementation is unspecified in the Common Lisp standard. It is fully possible that an implementation sometimes or even always ignores them.

Possible:

- they are simply ignored
- they are ignored in an interpreter, but used by a compiler
- they are used for optimization purposes
- they are used for compile-time type checks
- they are used for runtime type checks
- depends on the settings of safety&speed optimization quality

SBCL does more of above. Some implementations do nothing. Others provide a subset.

If you want runtime type checks in portable Common Lisp code, you'll need to use something like CHECK-TYPE in your code. Note that there are limits on possible runtime type checks, given the limited expressiveness of runtime type information.